# AngularJS, Karma: Unable to get promise resolve work for indexedDB wrapper

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, localforage

I am using [localforage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/) and had a angularjs wrapper to get item and give a promise object

Factory.js

```
service.prototype.getItem = function getItem(key) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   localforage.getItem(key).then(function (item) {
     //some calculations
     deferred.resolve(item);
   }
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Factory.spec.js

```
it('should get item', function (done) {
   mocks.inject(function ($rootScope, $httpBackend, service) {
      service.getItem('test').then(function(item) {
         expect(item).toBe('some value');
         done();
      });
      $rootScope.$digest();
   });
}
```

In the above code, service callback is getting triggered properly and getting the value. But unable to get callback triggered in spec.js

Answer (score 0):

Can't find where you dealing with `localforage`? I suppose the aim of the test is to check some important calculations, then probably you should do this

```
it('should get item', function () {
    spyOn(localforage, 'getItem').and.returnValue($q.resolve(item));

    service.getItem('test').then(function(responseAfterCalculations) {
         expect(responseAfterCalculations).toBe('some value');
    });
    $rootScope.$digest();
}
```

Basically, `localforage.getItem` method has its own [test](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/blob/master/test/test.api.js) in repo. In unit test you just testing your own function and 3rd party service implementation. So the best approach here is to simply mock `localforage`. If you want more complete test, you need a e2e approach, based on protractor for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand mocking locaforage is the best way. But in the example it seems end to end testing makes more sense. But I need to test more of my service works with localforage as expected

Comment: Probably this is the problem, I'm not familiar with `localforage`, but apparently this library connects to the server side. Karma + Jasmine stack does not allow this in tests, you should intercept all external requests. success callback is not being triggered because it cause an error, check error callback

Comment: the only thing I want to point out is that the problem is definitely not in the code you provided, most likely it has to do with `service.getItem`